# Want to insert timestamp through procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, time

I have this procedure

```
PROCEDURE insertSample
  (
    return_code_out OUT VARCHAR2,
    return_msg_out OUT VARCHAR2,
    sample_id_in IN table1.sample_id%TYPE,
    name_in IN table1.name%TYPE,
    address_in IN table1.address%TYPE
  )
  IS

  BEGIN
    return_code_out := '0000';
    return_msg_out := 'OK';

    INSERT INTO table1
    sample_id, name, address)
    VALUES
    (sample_id_in, name_in, address_in);


  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
      return_code_out := SQLCODE;
      return_msg_out := SQLERRM;


  END insertSample;
```

I want to add 4th column in table1 like day_time and add current day timestamp in it.. ho can i do that in this procedure.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you you have (or add) a column to the table outside of the procedure, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
  ADD( insert_timestamp TIMESTAMP );
```

you could modify your `INSERT` statement to be

```
   INSERT INTO table1
    sample_id, name, address, insert_timestamp)
    VALUES
    (sample_id_in, name_in, address_in, systimestamp);
```

In general, however, I would strongly suggest that you not return error codes and error messages from procedures.  If you cannot handle the error in your procedure, you should let the exception propagate up to the caller.  That is a much more sustainable method of writing code than trying to ensure that every caller to every procedure always correctly checks the return code.

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` will give you the current data and time.

and if you add the column with a default value you can leave your procedure as it is

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD when_created DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sysdate can provide all sorts of manipulation including the current date, or future and past dates.

http://edwardawebb.com/database-tips/sysdate-determine-start-previous-month-year-oracle-sql